# Lua Join by 1 char

Tags: lua

I need to join random special characters (!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*) to my string which looks like: 123456 , and I need to looks like that **1$&2$3%4^5**.

Is any way to do that with Lua? I was browsing some manual function, but nothing intersting found except join().

Comment: Lua is not an acronym; it is a proper name. You don't see people calling it PYTHON or JAVA or PERL.

Comment: You haven't really explained what algorithm you are trying to input. Which symbols go after which digits? Or is it based on the order of the digits or something else?

Comment: It's just random. There is an table = {'#','@','$'..etc} with a special characters, and (1,2) random special chars should be added after each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
local noise= {'#','@','$', '%'}
local s="123456"
print(s:gsub(".",function (c) return c..noise[math.random(1,#noise)] end))
```